# How can I create a Pandas DataFrame from a dictionary where ID numbers are part of the data frame and are not used to count columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I've created a dictionary from a text, using word IDs. My dictionary looks like this:

```
my_dict = dict()

34 red
42 blue
46 green
54 orange
61 purple
78 black
102 white
```

I'd like to create a DataFrame from this dictionary, using Pandas.

I've tried using pd.DataFrame.from_dict, but the program allows me to put only one column, like this:

```
mydict_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient ='index', columns=['COLOR'])
```

The ID numbers appear in bold, as if they were just counting the colors, like this:

```
       | COLOR  |
**34 **| red    |
**42 **| blue   |
**46 **| green  |
**54** | orange |
**61** | purple |
**78 **| black  |
**102**| white  |
```

I'd like to make them part of the DataFrame, adding two columns, 'ID' and 'COLOR', to get a DataFrame like the following:

```
|     | ID | COLOR  |
|**0**| 34 | red    |
|**1**| 42 | blue   |
|**2**| 46 | green  |
|**3**| 54 | orange |
|**4**| 61 | purple |
|**5**| 78 | black  |
|**6**| 102| white  |
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create it like this:

```
mydict_df = pd.DataFrame([(k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items()], columns=["id", "color"])
```

Although it might not have the best performance, if your data is very big.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
my_dict = {
    34:"red",
    42:"blue",
    46:"green",
    54:"orange",
    61:"purple",
    78:"black",
    102:"white"
}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": my_dict.keys(),
    "COLOR": my_dict.values()
})
```